# How to combine 2 json files into one

Tags: json

i have 2 json files i need to merge into one. how do i tell the code where the files are?

i haven't tried anything yet. not sure where to begin
i'm a desperate beginner. please help
I am trying to use this code to merge the 2 files

```
function mergejson() 
{
    $events = array();
    // open each jsonfile in this directory
    foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {  
        // get the contents of the the current file
        $data[] =json_decode($filename, true);
        $events= array_merge($events,$data);
    }
    $file_name ='merge.json';
    $events =json_encode($events,true);
    file_put_contents($file_name,$events);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where is that you read the file. Also, why `$data[]`? You are trying to get an associative array as `$data`, not as an element of `$data`.

And the second parameter of `json_encode` is not a boolean but a flag

```
<?php
function mergejson() 
{
    $events = array();
    // open each jsonfile in this directory
    foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
        // get the contents of the the current file
        $json = file_get_contents($filename);
        // then decodes to an associative array
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        $events= array_merge($events,$data);
    }
    $file_name ='merge.json';
    $events =json_encode($events, JSON_HEX_QUOT);
    file_put_contents($file_name,$events);       
}
```

Comment: I am trying to combine these 2 json files.file:///C:/Users/bucke/Downloads/recipes_api_dump.json file ///C:/Users/bucke/Downloads/items_api_dump.json

Comment: You will have to install PHP on your computer if you want to do it locally then use the PHP CLI